# How to display products from subcategory to parent category in opencart?

Tags: categories, product, opencart

I'm trying to find a solution but still no luck. I want to display all products from subcategories to parent category.

I'm using Opencart 1.5.3.1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After reading the source, I figured it out:

In catalog/controller/product/category.php (or wherever you're calling function model_catalog_product->getProducts) you have to add `filter_sub_category = true`:

```
$data = array(
    'filter_category_id' => $top_category,
    'filter_sub_category' => true,
    'sort'               => $sort,
    'order'              => $order,
    'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,
    'limit'              => $limit
);

$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
```

Make sure you check the other answers if you're using a later version ;)

Comment: This is really helpful. simple solution, great impact for user experience.

Comment: Just to clarify, this modifies the core files of OpenCart, which is rather nasty. Not that working with vQmod is not ugly as hell as well...

Comment: Great Solution. Thank You Sir

Comment: I agree, worked nicely even in the newer versions (2.0.3.1), the var name just changed to `$filter_data`, it's at the line 170.

Comment: I'm sorry @IvanStin, this Q is quite old and says I'm using v1.5.3.1. Perhaps someone from the community can check 2.3

Answer (score 7):

Another solution, rather than modifying the core files directly, is to use [vQmod](http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/) to modify the file for you. That way when you upgrade to a new version, you won't have to re-install any custom modifications you've made.

Below is an the code you'd use to accomplish this in vQmod:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>Display products in sub-categories while browsing a parent category</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.4.0</vqmver>
    <author>Jay Williams - jay@myd3.com</author>
    <file name="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA['filter_category_id' => $category_id,]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA['filter_sub_category' => true,]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/8044763

Answer (score 4):

catalog/controller/product/category.php

For Opencart Version 2.1.0.2, the solution of Ignacio works fines as well just that:

> `$data (of version 1.5.x)` is now called
>
> `$filter_data (line #169)`

Then just add the line

'filter_sub_category' => true,

after line #170 (`'filter_category_id' => $category_id,`)

Thanks Ignacio!

Answer (score 1):

the vqmod method is the best and works easily. just add that file and anything.xml and place it in vqmod > xml

Answer (score 1):

Just contributing with one more information, newest versions uses "ocmod", OpenCart's own vqmod feature. It can work the same way through there.

Answer (score 0):

For Opencart 3.x:
./catalog/controller/product/category.php

find:

```
'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
```

add after:

```
'filter_sub_category' => true,
```

**After change file, go to "Modification" and "Clear" and "Update" button click**